# How do I make a column's value set to position index of the entity in the list?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have two entities, Question and Answer, that have a One-to-Many relationship. When a user creates a Question, he/she can specify from 2 to 4 Answers as multiple choice. The Question table has an id (primary key) and prompt column. The Answer table has question_id, order, and text columns and question_id and order columns are primary keys (composite) in the table. The question_id is foreign key that refers to the id of the question in Question table. The order column specifies what option # it is of the question. I am trying figure out how I would do the mapping between Question and Answer class (using annotations) so that when I insert a new question, the order column in the Answer table gets a value between 0 to 3 (4 answers) depending on how many answers the user specified for the question in the UI. So if the created a Question with with 3 answers, the two tables would look like the the following:

Question Table:

id prompt

500, "this is question with id 500"

AnswerTable records:

question_id, order, text

500, 0, answer1; 500, 1, answer2; 500, 2, answer3;

I have the following so far and it doesn't work:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "question")
public class Question {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "prompt")
    private String prompt;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question")
    @OrderColumn(name = "order")
    private List<Answer> answers;
}


@Entity
@Table
public class Answer{
    @Embeddable
    private class AnswerId {
        @Column(name="question_id")
        private Integer questionId;

        @Column(name="order")
        private Integer order;         
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    private AnswerId id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="question_id")
    private Question question;

    @Column(name="text")
    private String text;
}
```

I get a mapping exception: "Repeated column in mapping for entity: Answer column: question_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")". I did read in some places that Hibernate doesn't support using @mappedBy and @OrderColumn annotations together. How do I make this work? Also, currently the Answer class has a reference to Question object but I do not ever need to access a Question from a Answer, so how can I remove that reference and still make this entire mapping work? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probem is because your `Answer` entity maps the `question_id` column to two properties in which both are marked via annotation to allow the field to be altered.

You can change your mapping as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Answer {
  /* other stuff */
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "question_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private Question question;
}
```

You can also add a helper method to your domain model class to help keep these values in sync via some business code if you wish like:

```
public class Answer {
  public void linkQuestion(Question question) { 
    getId().setQuestionId(question.getId());
    this.question = question;
  }
}
```

You want to however avoid doing any type of changes like this in your `setQuestion` method because this can cause issues with hibernate's dirty checking.

**UPDATE**

Yes you can have a unidirectional `@OneToMany` mapping.

```
@Entity
public class Question {
  /* other stuff */
  @OneToMany
  @JoinColumn(name = "QUESTION_ID")
  @OrderColumn(name = "order")
  private List<Answer> answers;

  /* utility method for adding an answer to question */
  public void addAnswer(Answer answer) {
    if(answers == null)
      answers = new ArrayList<>();
    answer.getId().setQuestionId(this.id);
    answers.add(answer);
  }

}
```

In your `Answer` entity remove the `Question` property and related annotations. The utility method simply shows you how'd you still make the relationship when you want to add an `Answer` entity to your `Question`.

Comment: Making the modifications to the annotation did fix the error I was getting. I still have some more testing to do, so I will accept your answer once I have it do what I want. Also, is it possible to remove the Question reference from Answer (@ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "question_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private Question question;) class completely and still have this work as I have explained it in the original post?

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses.